# Adding invariance restriction leads to eigenvalue close to zero - can invariance be stated, nevertheless?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am testing invariance between two groups. Configural and metric invariance is given. When adding the restriction of equal intercepts, lavaan gives me the warning that the smallest eigenvalue is close to zero (albeit positive) and that this might indicate that the model is not identified. Model fit is great, however, and if I would only consider model fit, I would state that scalar invariance is also given.

I noticed that the latent intercepts in my previous models were estimated to be zero. When introducing the restriction of equal intercepts, they are still zero in one group but negative in the other group. Not sure whether this is relevant.

**Can the model become unidentified by adding restrictions? Can I still state invariance despite the lavaan warning?**

This is the model syntax:

```
info =~ EU03 + EU04 + EU07 + EU09 + EU10
cons =~ EU01 + EU02 + EU13 + EU14
norm =~ NU02 + NU04 + NU05 + NU07 + NU08 + NU10 + NU14
eu =~ info + cons
```

This is how I fit the model:

```
mi_set_scalar = cfa(model,
                data = df_items,
                estimator = "MLR",
                cluster = "REF",
                meanstructure = T,
                group = "set",
                group.equal = c("loadings", "intercepts"))
```

And these are the resulting fit indices:

```
CFI.robust = 0.974
TLI.robust = 0.972
RMSEA.robust = .065
```

**EDIT: Full output**

```
    lavaan 0.6.14 ended normally after 87 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                       106
  Number of equality constraints                    30

  Number of observations per group:                  
    oil                                           1608
    company                                       1608
  Number of clusters [REF]:                          
    oil                                            402
    company                                        402

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                              1912.182    1217.955
  Degrees of freedom                               228         228
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.570
    Yuan-Bentler correction (Mplus variant)                      
  Test statistic for each group:
    oil                                        954.152     607.742
    company                                    958.031     610.213

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                             59235.913   32898.081
  Degrees of freedom                               240         240
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.801

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.971       0.970
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.970       0.968
                                                                 
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                         0.974
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                            0.972

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)             -69915.023  -69915.023
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.394
      for the MLR correction                                      
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)     -68958.932  -68958.932
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.664
      for the MLR correction                                      
                                                                 
  Akaike (AIC)                              139982.046  139982.046
  Bayesian (BIC)                            140443.814  140443.814
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (SABIC)     140202.329  140202.329

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.068       0.052
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.065       0.050
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.071       0.054
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.000       0.078
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.000       0.000
                                                                 
  Robust RMSEA                                               0.065
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                     0.062
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                     0.069
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                         0.000
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                         0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.030       0.030

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                        Robust.cluster
  Information                                  Observed
  Observed information based on                 Hessian


Group 1 [oil]:

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  info =~                                            
    EU03              1.000                          
    EU04    (.p2.)    0.989    0.010   98.235    0.000
    EU07    (.p3.)    1.010    0.009  111.361    0.000
    EU09    (.p4.)    0.960    0.011   89.097    0.000
    EU10    (.p5.)    0.984    0.010   94.213    0.000
  cons =~                                            
    EU01              1.000                          
    EU02    (.p7.)    1.073    0.013   85.373    0.000
    EU13    (.p8.)    1.052    0.012   86.782    0.000
    EU14    (.p9.)    1.043    0.011   94.105    0.000
  norm =~                                            
    NU02              1.000                          
    NU04    (.11.)    1.071    0.015   71.528    0.000
    NU05    (.12.)    1.048    0.018   58.748    0.000
    NU07    (.13.)    1.108    0.019   58.870    0.000
    NU08    (.14.)    1.071    0.016   68.903    0.000
    NU10    (.15.)    1.098    0.020   55.627    0.000
    NU14    (.16.)    1.042    0.015   68.786    0.000
  eu =~                                              
    info              1.000                          
    cons    (.18.)    0.961    0.017   57.790    0.000

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  norm ~~                                            
    eu                1.282    0.066   19.472    0.000

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .EU03    (.40.)    3.955    0.053   74.015    0.000
   .EU04    (.41.)    3.720    0.052   71.008    0.000
   .EU07    (.42.)    3.836    0.054   70.463    0.000
   .EU09    (.43.)    3.620    0.052   70.266    0.000
   .EU10    (.44.)    3.628    0.054   67.654    0.000
   .EU01    (.45.)    3.457    0.053   64.995    0.000
   .EU02    (.46.)    3.741    0.054   68.679    0.000
   .EU13    (.47.)    3.630    0.054   67.380    0.000
   .EU14    (.48.)    3.563    0.053   67.547    0.000
   .NU02    (.49.)    3.282    0.045   72.684    0.000
   .NU04    (.50.)    3.566    0.045   79.719    0.000
   .NU05    (.51.)    3.440    0.045   76.713    0.000
   .NU07    (.52.)    3.759    0.045   84.468    0.000
   .NU08    (.53.)    3.302    0.046   71.442    0.000
   .NU10    (.54.)    3.817    0.045   84.636    0.000
   .NU14    (.55.)    3.241    0.045   71.382    0.000
   .info              0.000                          
   .cons              0.000                          
    norm              0.000                          
    eu                0.000                          

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .EU03              0.479    0.035   13.859    0.000
   .EU04              0.414    0.028   14.778    0.000
   .EU07              0.492    0.040   12.278    0.000
   .EU09              0.485    0.035   13.841    0.000
   .EU10              0.471    0.033   14.385    0.000
   .EU01              0.751    0.045   16.695    0.000
   .EU02              0.547    0.038   14.578    0.000
   .EU13              0.652    0.043   15.223    0.000
   .EU14              0.485    0.032   15.097    0.000
   .NU02              0.869    0.051   16.939    0.000
   .NU04              0.735    0.048   15.448    0.000
   .NU05              0.830    0.055   14.990    0.000
   .NU07              0.811    0.049   16.611    0.000
   .NU08              0.668    0.044   15.309    0.000
   .NU10              0.873    0.064   13.717    0.000
   .NU14              0.723    0.043   16.922    0.000
   .info              0.300    0.039    7.659    0.000
   .cons              0.147    0.036    4.050    0.000
    norm              1.608    0.067   23.832    0.000
    eu                1.952    0.084   23.255    0.000


Group 2 [company]:

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  info =~                                            
    EU03              1.000                          
    EU04    (.p2.)    0.989    0.010   98.235    0.000
    EU07    (.p3.)    1.010    0.009  111.361    0.000
    EU09    (.p4.)    0.960    0.011   89.097    0.000
    EU10    (.p5.)    0.984    0.010   94.213    0.000
  cons =~                                            
    EU01              1.000                          
    EU02    (.p7.)    1.073    0.013   85.373    0.000
    EU13    (.p8.)    1.052    0.012   86.782    0.000
    EU14    (.p9.)    1.043    0.011   94.105    0.000
  norm =~                                            
    NU02              1.000                          
    NU04    (.11.)    1.071    0.015   71.528    0.000
    NU05    (.12.)    1.048    0.018   58.748    0.000
    NU07    (.13.)    1.108    0.019   58.870    0.000
    NU08    (.14.)    1.071    0.016   68.903    0.000
    NU10    (.15.)    1.098    0.020   55.627    0.000
    NU14    (.16.)    1.042    0.015   68.786    0.000
  eu =~                                              
    info              1.000                          
    cons    (.18.)    0.961    0.017   57.790    0.000

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  norm ~~                                            
    eu                1.617    0.067   24.249    0.000

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .EU03    (.40.)    3.955    0.053   74.015    0.000
   .EU04    (.41.)    3.720    0.052   71.008    0.000
   .EU07    (.42.)    3.836    0.054   70.463    0.000
   .EU09    (.43.)    3.620    0.052   70.266    0.000
   .EU10    (.44.)    3.628    0.054   67.654    0.000
   .EU01    (.45.)    3.457    0.053   64.995    0.000
   .EU02    (.46.)    3.741    0.054   68.679    0.000
   .EU13    (.47.)    3.630    0.054   67.380    0.000
   .EU14    (.48.)    3.563    0.053   67.547    0.000
   .NU02    (.49.)    3.282    0.045   72.684    0.000
   .NU04    (.50.)    3.566    0.045   79.719    0.000
   .NU05    (.51.)    3.440    0.045   76.713    0.000
   .NU07    (.52.)    3.759    0.045   84.468    0.000
   .NU08    (.53.)    3.302    0.046   71.442    0.000
   .NU10    (.54.)    3.817    0.045   84.636    0.000
   .NU14    (.55.)    3.241    0.045   71.382    0.000
   .info             -0.242    0.031   -7.860    0.000
   .cons             -0.160    0.029   -5.484    0.000
    norm             -0.589    0.059   -9.922    0.000
    eu               -0.490    0.047  -10.399    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .EU03              0.486    0.041   11.804    0.000
   .EU04              0.343    0.027   12.843    0.000
   .EU07              0.433    0.031   13.760    0.000
   .EU09              0.385    0.028   13.934    0.000
   .EU10              0.402    0.028   14.258    0.000
   .EU01              0.592    0.042   14.112    0.000
   .EU02              0.450    0.035   12.865    0.000
   .EU13              0.447    0.033   13.430    0.000
   .EU14              0.442    0.030   14.868    0.000
   .NU02              0.676    0.046   14.658    0.000
   .NU04              0.603    0.037   16.194    0.000
   .NU05              0.771    0.049   15.749    0.000
   .NU07              0.799    0.061   13.055    0.000
   .NU08              0.570    0.035   16.045    0.000
   .NU10              0.762    0.056   13.713    0.000
   .NU14              0.603    0.040   15.242    0.000
   .info              0.209    0.034    6.196    0.000
   .cons              0.071    0.032    2.174    0.030
    norm              1.789    0.072   24.839    0.000
    eu                2.228    0.083   26.697    0.000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned that the model might not be identified you should try the model with different starting values and see if it converges to the same place. If it converges to the same place, it's identified.

It's not clear (to me) what the eu latent variable is doing. Can you post output?

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I did some further digging and I actually found that the eu latent variable is causing the trouble. If I remove it, the model is fitted without any warning and identification is given. I was under the impression that it would not make a difference (i.e., models would be equivalent) whether eu is included or whether info and cons correlate directly with norm instead. Do you have any idea why the eu variable might be the problem? Are the models with and without eu not equivalent?

Comment: eu has two loadings, to estimate one parameter. Constrain them to be equal and the model will be equivalent with and without eu.

Comment: Your model syntax and output don't appear (to me) to match. Why does eu have loadings to the EU variables in the model, but not the syntax?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. In the syntax, eu has loadings to info and cons. In the output, it is the same. eu does not have direct loadings to any of the EUXX variables.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue following this paper. I had some mispecifications in my model given the second order factor. Maybe this will be of help to someone: https://mda.gesis.org/index.php/mda/article/download/2017.11/219